# Xpath by ID or class does not work

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am not able to run my `selenium webdriver` tests its not detecting `xPath`. I tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='manageEvents']")).click(); for the
```

below is `HTML` code:

```
<head>

    <body style="height: 100%; background-color: aliceblue;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Left Side Bar-->
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row leftMenu">
                            <div class="row leftMenu">
                                <div class="row leftMenu">
                                    <div id="manageEvents" class="menuBlk">
                                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open" style="font-size:68px;margin-top:20px" />
                                        <h3 style="margin-top:0px">Manage Events</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Feed -->
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                <!-- Right Side Bar -->
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                                </div>
                            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean `does not work`? Did you get exception or just nothing happens?

Comment: Yes, i got the following exception:org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[@id='manageEvents']'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/*[@id='manageEvents']']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: The exception is now: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='manageEvents']"}

Comment: Does the `<body>` element on provided `HTML` code is the main document `body` or it's an `iframe` `body`?

Comment: Its not the main document, its a iframe body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to wait until required element appears in `DOM` and become clickable:

```
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='manageEvents']")));
element.click();
```

or if your element located inside an `iframe`, you need to switch to that `iframe` before searching for element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='manageEvents']")).click();
```

P.S. If there are more than one `iframe` on page this code might not work, so provide `HTML` for target `iframe` to get exact selector for it

Comment: Thank you so much! the iframe switch worked for me..! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try not to go down to the root of the tree and make

```
//*[@id="manageEvents"]
```

Comment: it gives the exception: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='manageEvents']"}

Comment: it gives the exception: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='manageEvents']"}